# Set UITableViewCell in full screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want to set `UITableViewCell` in full screen when user select cell with bouncing animation. I shared link below. I want same like this.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9k_Shyb5v62eFdxWXhYeXV3a0E

I set view inside cell. But I can't set it in full screen with animation.

Below is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    int index = [cell.accessibilityIdentifier intValue];
    CGFloat delay = 0.0f;
    if (indexSelected == (int)indexPath.row)
    {
        //COLLAPSE
        indexSelected = -1111111111;
        UIView *viewController = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TAG_DETAIL_CONTROLLER];
        [viewController removeFromSuperview];

        tableViewList.frame = frameTableViewList;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        btnBack.hidden = YES;
        indexSelected = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        //EXPAND
        if (indexSelected < 0)
            indexSelected = index;
        else
        {
            int indexPrevious = indexSelected;
            indexSelected = (int)indexPath.row;
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPrevious inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            delay = 0.3;
        }

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


            CGRect frame = tableViewList.frame;
            frame.origin.y = 0;
            frame.size.height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame);
            tableViewList.frame = frame;
            btnBack.hidden = NO;
        });
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
            cell = [self reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIView *viewController = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TAG_DETAIL_CONTROLLER];
    if (indexSelected >= 0 && indexSelected == (int)indexPath.row)
        [self addDiamondDetailView:cell index:(int)indexPath.row];
    else
    {
        if (indexSelected == -1111111111)
        {
            CGRect frame = cell.frame;
            frame.size.height = cellHeight;
            cell.frame = frame;
            cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(cell.frame), CGRectGetHeight(cell.frame));
        }

        [viewController removeFromSuperview];
    }

    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    return cell;
}

- (void)addDiamondDetailView:(UITableViewCell *)cell index:(int)index
{
    DetailVC = [[DetailViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
DetailVC.selectedStoneInfo = (StoneInfo *)[arrStone objectAtIndex:index];
    DetailVC._STONE_DETAIL_TYPE = self._RESULT_PAGE_TYPE == RESULT_MY_CART ? STONE_DETAIL_CART : STONE_DETAIL_RESULT;
DetailVC.delegate = self;
DetailVC.view.tag = TAG_DETAIL_CONTROLLER;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:stoneDetailVC.view];

    //Cell Frame
    CGRect frame = cell.bounds;
    frame.size.height = cellDetailHeight;
    cell.frame = frame;
    cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(cell.frame), CGRectGetHeight(cell.frame));

    //Stone Detail VC  Frame
    frame = stoneDetailVC.view.frame;
DetailVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(stoneDetailVC.view.frame), cellDetailHeight);
}
```

I've added `ViewController` into cell as sub view. I want to set table cell in view full screen with bounce animation. Please help me.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is an view controller transition.

Comment: If user click on any cell it will be expanded in full screen n my view controller added as sub view in cell content view....

Comment: You are better off transitioning to a full screen view controller with an animation so it looks like you are expanding the cell, but you really aren't.

Comment: How to achieve this? I don't know. Is there any solution?

Comment: Hey... I solved this...

Comment: If you solved this, could you please answer your own question with the solution? I'm sure it will be useful for someone else (*like me (!)*).